# Mysql Foreign Key Usage

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying my first hand at creating a mysql database for a simple blog. I'm having trouble understanding foreign keys and their appropriate relations. If someone can explain in "layman's" terms I'll be very happy.

I have a table called users that has the basics of fields (username, email, password etc) which I've created a user_type field and set it to INT. I've created the corresponding table called user_type and added two fields (one being the type_id = primary key and the other been the type = VARCHAR).

My question is:

Am I correct in understanding that I connect the two tables together by setting the foreign key link from the user_type INT in the users table to reference the type_id from the user_type table?

Comment: Before you bang your head against the wall: you need to use `InnoDB` tables; if you use `MyISAM`, foreign keys will not be enforced (but you won't be warned about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

From [SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

> A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table.

So in your example, the `user_type` id in table user_types would be the primary key, and the `user_type` int in table users would be the foreign key entry.

This enforces that an entry in table user_types has to exist before it can be used in table users.

Comment: Do I need to do anything with CASCADE, NO ACTION etc or can I just leave it blank?

Comment: Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: thanks but it's too technical and kind of need a 3rd grade explanation?

Comment: CASCADE: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table.

RESTRICT: Rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table. Specifying RESTRICT (or NO ACTION) is the same as omitting the ON DELETE or ON UPDATE clause.

Comment: thanks again - so much simple when it's explained, honestly don't know why they don't explain it like this for everything - makes it much easier for learning.

Answer (score 0):

You referencing from user to usertype:

n users have one user_type

If you create the table with an sql statement it should include something like this in the user part:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `username` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL ,
  `user_type` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `user_to_usertype_idx` (`user_type` ASC) ,
    CONSTRAINT `user_to_usertype`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_type` )
    REFERENCES `user_type` (`type_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

You have to create user_type before you create user, otherwise you will get a failure.

Comment: when you say - you have to create user_type first do you mean I have create the table first or every sql statement has to start with the user_type field?

Comment: The table has to be created first, if u want the referencing with a constraint. If there is no user_type table the constraint cant be created and u will get an error. You can also work without constraints... But then you might have users with an invalid user_type (user_type might not exist). Constraints are helping you to have clean data in your database.